# Celery task delay calling convention in 4.2.0

Tags: python, celery

I recently upgraded celery from version `4.0.2` to `4.2.0`, the following was working prior to upgrading and I can't find what I need to change to make it work on the latest.

Example:

```
@task
def run_mytask(pk):
    print pk
```

`task = tasks.run_mytask.delay(pk)`

Now throws the following error:

```
TypeError: unbound method shadow_name() must be called with run_mytask instance as first argument (got tuple instance instead)
```

Comment: Can you try doing `@task(bind=True)` ?

Comment: @sytech `TypeError: run_mytask() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

pk here is just an integer

Comment: Sorry, when supplying `bind` you should also put `self` as the first argument, which is the task instance. e.g. `def sometask(self, args)`-- Also note that celery `4.2` has not yet been released. AFAICT, 4.1 is the latest release....

Comment: @sytech Same error as the original one with that, I'm on the pre-offical release because of a bug in `4.1` https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4314

Comment: @sytech Marking this as closed, thanks for the help looks like I just needed to reinstall celery from git since I last did it a month ago

Comment: Yeah, seems it was fixed here https://github.com/celery/celery/pull/4572/files 15 days ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the issue was fixed in [celery#4572](https://github.com/celery/celery/pull/4572).

As discussed in comments, pulling down the latest version and installing celery with this change resolves this issue for you, since your version did not contain these changes.